# Optimal command that links static libraries

Tags: c++, g++

I have many static libs to be linked to my project. I do this by describing path and file name (like `../lib/libaws-crt-cpp.a` ) in command line:

```
g++ main.cpp -I ../include/  ../lib/libaws-crt-cpp.a ../lib/libDiscovery-cpp.a
```

I have much more files to be linked ant is too boring write `../lib/` each time. Can I make this shorter? Can I somehow omit path?

Comment: If the pattern is as simple as your example lets me think, then all you need to write is `../lib/lib*.a`. That assumes that the order does not matter, though.

Comment: Don't write compiler commands by hand, use a proper build system like cmake or meson. If you must do it the hard way then `-L../lib -laws-crt-cpp -lDiscovery-cpp` would be a little shorter

Comment: Can't you use cmake or something to do it for you?